# Why can't I store multiple return value from a function in separate variable after a while it was executed?

Tags: python-3.x, function

[Same piece of code in two cells while first one is not working second one is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfbVQ.png)

I expected first one would work. In second one I redefined the same function again and executed. This time I got the expected result. can anyone explain why first one is not working. What mistake have I done?

Comment: Please paste your code in snippets, it will help us to use your code and give you answer

Answer (score 1):

Key Points:

1. Python scripts are interpreted from top to bottom.
2. When there are multiple objects with the same name, only the last one takes effect.
   [image]

[image]

1. In Figure 1, the greetings in "greet1,greet2 = greetings()" are of type tuple, and calls of type tuple are not followed by a pair of parentheses around the corresponding variable name, so the error is reported.
2. In Figure 2, the greetings in "greet1,greet2 = greetings()" are of type function, and a call to a function type is made by adding a pair of parentheses to the corresponding function name, so Figure 2 is correct.